# Converting matrices L and U output by dgssv() of SuperLU to triples format

Tags: matrix, scipy, matrix-factorization, io

How can I convert matrices `L` and `U` output by `dgssvx()` of SuperLU to triples format (to matrix market format)? Also how can I convert input matrix `A` in triples format (in matrix market format) to the format required by SuperLU? What is the easiest way to perform these format conversions?

Comment: The answer to this question can be found by reading the SuperLU user guide.

Comment: Dear @py, is there a solution using `pysparse` or `scipy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that the interfaces had changed and developed within the last 5 years. As of right now, the result can be achieved using the standard functionality of `scipy` (as requested in the comments).

- Use [scipy.io.mmread](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.mmread.html#scipy.io.mmread) to load the matrix from MatrixMarket file into sparse or dense scipy matrix. I would assume that your matrix is originally sparse, therefore you are good to go.
- Now, [scipy.sparse.linalg.splu](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.splu.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.splu) can be used (or iLU if you opt for incomplete factorization).

Conversely, you can use

- [scipy.io.mmwrite](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.mmwrite.html#scipy.io.mmwrite) to write out your matrices into the MatrixMarket files.